# How to check if a string contains French letters?

Tags: java

In Java, how can we check a string to see if it contains French letters?

Comment: Make an array of french letters and check against that?

Comment: What are "french letters"? Latin characters? Specific letters that only appear in French (if so, which ones)?

Comment: thanks, I mean French special characters (the ones with accent!).

Comment: Check this table http://www.asciitable.com/ It will show you the decimal value for the characters your looking for.

Comment: A regular expression: `[every French character]+`

Comment: Are there few enough of them that you could just make a list? Like if I wanted to do this for German, I'd create the array {Ü, ü, Ö, ö, Ä, ä, ß} and see if any character in my string is in that array.

Comment: A list of [special characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_alphabet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static boolean containsFrench(String s) {
    Pattern frenchPattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)[çèéêîôœû]");
    return frenchPattern.matcher(s).find();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the notion of a "french letter" is poorly defined, the simplest way to solve this would be to create an array containing all letters that you think qualify, and then just test each character in the string to see if it is in the array:

(I'm not going to write the code for you because this is something that anyone who has done a Java course or tutorial should be able to write in five minutes.  And if you can't do it in 5 minutes, then *you need to practice* by doing it yourself.)

There are more elegant and/or more efficient ways to do this.  But simple is good for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution - you might want to check that the list is exhaustive (for example, I have not included accented large caps or the ÿ which is not very common) but the concept should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Character> frenchLetters = new HashSet<> (Arrays.asList('â', 'à', 'ç', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'è', 'ï', 'î', 'ô', 'û', 'ù'));
    String s = "abcdà";
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (frenchLetters.contains(c)) {
            System.out.println("Found a French letter: " + c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This probably needs to be `frenchLetters.contains(Character.toLowerCase(c))`

Comment: @BrendanLong `Character.toLowerCase` is not locale aware so that could lead to unexpected results. `String.toLowerCase(Locale.FR)` would make sense. But I don't know if all accented large caps are valid...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public boolean hasFrenchCharacter(String input) {
    if (input.contains("ù") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("û") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("ü") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("ÿ") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("à") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("â") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("æ") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("ç") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("é") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("è") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("ê") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("ë") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("ï") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("î") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("ô") == true) return true;
    if (input.contains("œ") == true) return true;
    return false;
}
```

It will return true if it has a French character, false otherwise.

Really this is not the way I would do it, I would do it this way:

```
public boolean hasFrenchCharacter(String input) {
    return input.contains("ù") ||
           input.contains("û") ||
           input.contains("ü");
    //and so on...
}
```

Comment: The `== true` is superfluous (could just be `if (input.contains("ù"))`, etc.), but besides that, I like this answer since it will probably make more sense to a beginner.